# Application.Exit() leaves debugger attached to something

Tags: c#

When I call Application.Exit(), the app seems to quit, but the debugger remains attached to some process and I have to hit the stop button.

I suspect this is because I'm running a TCP receive thread in the app, but aborting it on quit didn't seem to fix it, either.

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as "CSharp". The language is named "C#".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a background or foreground thread? Make it background, so it get's aborted on application quit.

Also, instead of hitting stop, pause the debugger, and see where in the code it is.

Comment: Thanks for the pause tip; hadn't occurred to me for some reason.

Comment: It was because of a blocking socket connection. Answer accepted because the pause debugger tip made me find the problem.